# Como trabalhar com mais de um arquivo python?

Tags: python

Eu aprendi a importar módulos, mas não sei como, por exemplo, criar uma classe em um arquivo separado e incluir ela no programa principal, como fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salve o arquivo na mesma pasta do arquivo original e você pode importá-lo sem maiores problemas.

arquivo1.py

```
class Classe:
    def __init__():
        ....
```

arquivo2.py

```
from arquivo1 import Classe

obj = Classe()
......
```

Comment: Funcionou eu só tava errando que eu tava dando apenas import arquivo ao inves de from arquivo import classe

Comment: Não tem problema em dar só import. Mas se você fizer `import arquivo1` terá que acessar sua classe fazendo `obj = arquivo1.Classe()`